# What is the maximum width for frame in iPad Application?

Tags: ipad, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator

my application like calendar view and i should set all views onload so should setup for every year 12 grid view but the iPad(3) give me memory worrying after build 13 grid view and it should cause it is a high data so i search for another way and i found something could infinite & StreetScroller but when i try it the data should be fix (ex: can't handle the position to change data load the next year) is that correct or i miss. up and there is a way to use this and i don't know it ???
plz help me to find to solution ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're implementing a calendar type view, and you get memory issues with large amounts of data.

In answer to the title of this question, there is no maximum width for a frame (I assume you mean UIView) in an iOS application. **But**, it is important to make sure you manage your memory correctly. For example, I could have a view that is 749202 pixels wide, and contains detailed charts/text/images/etc... If I filled out this View in full when it first loaded, the application would crash; it would use too much memory.

In order to make sure this doesn't occur, I need to optimize my memory usage. For example, I know that the maximum width of the iPad in portrait is 768 pts, and landscape is 1024 pts (discoverable via the width and height of a view's window). As such, I will only create/render my data when it is (or about to be) in view. This means I only have to render 0.1% of my total width at a time, which is a lot more manageable memory wise.

As to your specifc situation, the description is vague, and there isn't any code, so this is the best information I can give. In regards to the StreetScroller example (if I remember this is the WWDC sample project for UIScrollView), I don't know what issue you're having with that exactly.

Comment: thanks for you explanation , but the issue i have is with filling the data.

Comment: You need to be more clear then I'm afraid, I don't understand the problem you're having given the description you gave.

Comment: i will accept the answer because it the beast explain i found to now/